# Subscription for multiple tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

Is it possible to create a tag subscription that only notifies when 2 tags are present? If so, how?

I tried creating a subscription with the tag+tag format, but only the first tag was saved.

Comment: I don't think so.  I'd just subscribe to the more specific tag and hope.